# How to select a row by count and name in Access db vs

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have tried this code but it shows syntax error  `cant select * from tbl2 were like 1, 1999` 
I do that because `ccont` may match on the database and I have a delete code depend on it so if 2 `ccont` matches it deletes them both I want to check it with `ccont` and `modelnumbb` so it won't get deleted

`string coe = "DELETE * FROM tbl2 WHERE ccont , modelnumbb LIKE '" + textBox2.Text + "%','" + mdlnumber3.Text + "%'";`

Comment: What data type is ccont? Edit question to show sample data.

Comment: all of is string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

% is not standard wildcard character in Access query. The WHERE clause syntax is wrong. Try:

```
string coe = "DELETE * FROM tbl2 WHERE ccont LIKE '" + textBox2.Text + "*' AND modelnumbb LIKE '" + mdlnumber3.Text + "*'";
```

Might want to explore use of parameters to prevent SQL injection. Review [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Comment: thanks it worked i just changed * to % and worked

Comment: Wildcard for fields isn't even necessary for DELETE action because entire record is removed.